# AngularJS : How to bind data from dynamic url?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I'm newbie in AngularJS

We expose our data through REST APIs

```
/shop/2/mum
```

this url returns JSON and bind them like this

```
function ec2controller($scope, $http){
  $http.get("/shop/2/mum")
           .success(function(data){
                $scope.shopname = data.name;
                $scope.location = data.location;
                $scope.customer = data.customer;
    })
```

In html

```
<div class="shop">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
     <span class="shop-box">{{showname}}</span>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
     <span class="shop-box">{{location}]}</span>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

This works fine !

Now, we need to have a dynamic URL like

```
/shop/<user-id>/<location>
```

And i need to pass this url when i select an option from drop-down box, set the value in **{{shopname}}**, **{{location}}** accordingly. How to do this please guide me ?

**Thanks**

Comment: Is `shop/2` a viable route? or only when a `location` is also specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app.js you would have defined a series of routes that ui-router knows about. These routes can have dynamic sections. In your case you would need to do something like the following:

```
$stateProvider.state('shop', {
    url:"shop",
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        "body": {
            templateUrl: "partials/shop.jade",
            controller: "ShopController"
        }
    }
})
.state('shop.customer', {
    url: "/:customer",
    views: {
        "body": {
            templateUrl: "partials/shop.customer.jade",
            controller: "ShopCustomerController"
        }
    }
})
.state('shop.customer.location', {
    url: "/:location",
    views: {
        "body": {
            templateUrl: "partials/shop.customer.location.jade",
            controller: "ShopCustomerLocationController"
        }
    }
})
```

Note that this assumes `/shop` is set as an `abstract` meaning it wont be a resolvable route, you should follow this same standard if you want `/shop/2` to also not resolve.

Then in, for example the ShopCustomerLocationController, you can access the url parameters using the following:

```
$state.params.location; // would return "mum"
$state.params.customer; // would return "2" <-- note string not integer
```